# Run .exe with high priority without START command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Is it possible to run a process without the START command and set its priority?

e.g. `process.exe /HIGH --arg=value`

---

I am running a batch that runs a for loop with the same `process.ext` using different `value`'s. I would like to have all these lines in the same initial command prompt opened by this batch (and do not open any new command prompt).

Comment: Why would you not want to use START? Start seems to be perfect for what you want.

Comment: Sorry this is clearly due to my inexperience, it is for the reasons later described. Is there a way START would achieve this? (not new command - \B did not do the trick for some reason - and output all the results as lines ran in the current open prompt)

Comment: If the initial command prompt runs with high priority, start should run its command with high priority as well